Doubt in Apostol's Book Theorem 1.6
I have some doubt about the following theorem from Apostol's Mathematical Analysis [2nd Edition] that I found when I was trying to redo it from my understanding of it. I have taken the following statement of the proof from another question: Apostol Analysis Book Theorem 1.6.

Proof
First assume that ≥0,≥0  and use induction on =+.
If =0  then ==0,  and we can take =0  with ==0.
Assume then that the theorem has been proved for 0,1,2,3,4,…,−1.
By symmetry we can assume ≥.
If =0  take =,=1,=0.
If ≥1  we can apply the induction hypothesis to −  and ,
since their sum is =−≤−1.
Hence there is a common divisor   of −  and   of the form
=(−)+.
This   also divides (−)+=,  so   is a common divisor of 
and   and we have =+(−),  a linear combination of 
and .
To complete the proof we need to show that every common divisor
divides .  Since a common divisor divides   and ,  it also
divides the linear combination +(−)=.
This completes the proof if ≥0  and ≥0.

In the first step of the induction the divisor d is taken to be 0; though can 0 even be a divisor? I understand a divisor as a number that divides another and since division by 0 is generally undefined I am questioning its validity as a divisor. Is the induction from n=0 then unsound? And would an induction from n=1 resolve this, disregarding the case of n=0?

Yes, 0 can be a divisor. If $a$ and $b$ are integers, the definition of "$a$ is a divisor of $b$" is that there exists an integer $k$ such that $b = ak$. Notice that, even though it's called a divisor, the definition uses multiplication, not division. So division by zero is not a problem. However, it follows easily from the definition that if 0 is a divisor of $b$, then $b=0$.

That's quite significant, I had never encountered that specific case before. These terms should really come with a instruction manual and big disclaimer. (:
